# tikz/pgfplots advanced z-order axis/grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to have both the `axis on top` and the grid on the very bottom (or somewhere in between some other planes/lines/...) of a plot?

Example figure with `axis on top=true` but the grid on top is ugly:

[image]

Example figure with `axis on top=false` and the grid looks nice behind the yellow plane, but axes and arrows look bad behind the drawing.

[image]

Here is a tiny code example

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left] %axis on top
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=red] {0.1*x^2} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

Can anyone put the axis to the top without having the grid on top?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can make use of the `after end axis/.code` key here to redraw the axis lines after everything else is done. The macro for drawing the axes (and grid lines, tick marks and tick labels) is the internal macro `pgfplots@draw@axis`, so we need to make it available by assigning a new name without `@` first. Then we can define a new style that initially sets the axis lines, tick marks and tick labels to transparent, and uses the `after end axis/.code` to reset the opaqueness, hide the grid and call `pgfplots@draw@axis`.

This looks a bit intimidating at first, but once the style `axis lines on top` is defined, all you have to do in the axis itself is use the style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document}

\makeatletter \newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis} \makeatother

\pgfplotsset{axis line on top/.style={
  axis line style=transparent,
  ticklabel style=transparent,
  tick style=transparent,
  axis on top=false,
  after end axis/.append code={
    \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque,
      ticklabel style=opaque,
      tick style=opaque,
      grid=none}
    \pgfplotsdrawaxis}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,axis line on top]
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=red] {0.1*x^2} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: axis with grid behind, axis lines on top]

Comment: nice. I think I have to go a few layers deeper to unleash the full power of pgf/tikz :)

Comment: @Jake I know this here is quite old - but so is the need to improve layered graphics in pgfplots. I would appreciate if I could discuss some of the involved issues with you as you appear to be very experienced in tikz / TeX / pgfplots. If so, I would be glad to receive an E-Mail (for example ludewich  on users sourceforge net)

Comment: This just can't be the simplest solution for such a common problem... I mean, it's *natural* that axes go above a bar plot and grid goes below.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could plot it twice, first with the grid, and again without it, but with axis on top.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,enlargelimits=false] 
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=red] {0.1*x^2} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
     \begin{axis}[axis on top=true,enlargelimits=false] 
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=red] {0.1*x^2} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

I hope there is an other way as this requires plotting twice, but as far as I could tell there doesn't seem to be an easy way to separate the axis from the grid, but I could easily be wrong as I'm new to `pgfplots`.

However, in a pinch, I think this will yield your desired results.

Comment: the other solution provided is more proper, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @ kromuchi: Yes, it's a much better solution. I just put this one here in case nothing else showed up ;)