# Avoiding transparency

Tags: pgfplots, ghostscript

While trying to create a plot with pgfplots, I noticed that the output created by *ghostscript* with

```
gs -o main_opt.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite main.pdf
```

to optimize the PDF (size is reduced to ~50%) is different from the original PDF. In the legend, the border of the plot marks is reset from `solid` to the respective line style.

[image: broken plot marks]

My investigations hinted me towards problems with transparency and postscript. Unfortunately, I think that transparency is necessary within the [`axis line on top`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56259/25888) style to avoid the double-drawing of the axis, ticks and ticklabels.

**What might be the exact problem here? Why do the plot marks break, when I append `transparent` to the `tick style` (see MWE, below)?**

Is there maybe some other solution without transparency like a "dontdraw"/"draw" switch, similar to "transparent"/"opaque"?

---

The following example does not contain the `axis line on top` style but does reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    tick style=transparent,
    legend entries={1,2,3,4},
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1
    ]

    \addplot+[thick,solid,             mark options=solid,mark=*] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.2) (1,1)};
    \addplot+[thick,densely dashed,    mark options=solid,mark=square*] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.4) (1,1)};
    \addplot+[thick,densely dotted,    mark options=solid,mark=triangle*] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.6) (1,1)};
    \addplot+[thick,densely dashdotted,mark options=solid,mark=diamond*] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.8) (1,1)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

UPDATE: Thanks to @cfr, I could rewrite the `axis line on top` style to fit my needs. I disabled the handling of `ticklabel style` because I don't need need it and reenabling this with `ticklabel style=draw` would actually draw the boxes around them.

```
\makeatletter \newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis} \makeatother
\pgfplotsset{axis line on top/.style={
    %% before
    %axis line style=transparent,
    %ticklabel style=transparent,
    %tick style=transparent,
    %% now
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    axis on top=false,

    after end axis/.append code={
      \pgfplotsset{
        %% before
        %axis line style=opaque,
        %ticklabel style=opaque,
        %tick style=opaque,
        %% now
        axis line style=draw,
        tick style=draw,

        grid=none}
      \pgfplotsdrawaxis}
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean like `draw=none`? (Haven't tried it in this context, but that's the usual TikZ override.)

Comment: @cfr I was obviously missing the obvious... Still, I don't know *why* it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: But it still doesn't work?

Comment: @cfr It works with the added style. The question is: why didn't it work? The transparency of ticks or axis lines should be unrelated to the style of marks! I guess this is a question for Christian Feuersänger...

Comment: Ideally yes. Or somebody who knows `pgfplots` well. (I know a tiny bit about it from answering questions here, but no more than that.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to (problematic) optimization of external script (Ghostscript and ImageMagick)