# How to draw the region of inequality?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Everyone, I would like to draw the region

```
\begin{align*}
  x_1 + x_2 &\ge 3 \\
  2x_1 - x_2 &\le 5 \\
  -x_1 + 2x_2 &\le 3
\end{align*}
```

Here is my code to draw the region of inequality:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \label{fig:p3:c1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[axis on top,smooth,
        axis line style=very thick,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ymin=-1,ymax=6,xmin=-1,xmax=6,
        xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$,grid=major
      ]
        \addplot[thick,pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=blue!30!white,
          domain=-10:4]{3-x} -| (axis cs:50, 50);
        \addplot[thick,pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=green!60!white,
          domain=-10:12]{-5+2*x} -| (axis cs: -50,50);
        \addplot[thick,pattern=grid,pattern color=yellow,
          domain=-10:10]{3/2+x/2} -| (axis cs: 20,0);
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10]{3-x};
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10]{-5+2*x};
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10]{3/2+x/2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Problem 4, Part A}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code have several problems.

1. In order not let pattern to cover the line, I draw every function twice.  Can we draw the pattern just before draw all the line?
2. The grid overlap show before the line. (I also want to let axis on the top)
3. How to fill the region above/under a curve/line?  As you can see, I just use a very ugly way.  It will draw unnecessary line (now it is overlapped with axis) and it is not beautiful.  I need to modify the coordinate every time I change other things.  Any better method?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Thanks for providing the bulk of the needed code.  But, it is better to provide a fully  compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as @cmhughes has done for you.  BTW, excellent first question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) I don't know if there is any way to draw the lines just once (except to use `draw=none` the first time)

2) The solution in the following code comes from [tikz/pgfplots advanced z-order axis/grid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/tikz-pgfplots-advanced-z-order-axis-grid).

3) Each area covers at most three vertices of the axis box, depending on the inequality sign, so you can address them via the `rel axis cs` syntax. You can define a new command once for all.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={
             \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque,
                          grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}

\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:0,1) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{figure}[htpb] 
    \centering 
    \label{fig:p3:c1} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
        axis line style=very thick, 
        axis x line=bottom, 
        axis y line=left, 
         ymin=-1,ymax=5.99,xmin=-1,xmax=5.99, 
         xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$,grid=major 
      ] 
        \addplot [draw=none, pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-10:4]
                 {3-x} \drawge; 
        \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-10:12]
                 {-5+2*x} \drawge;
        \addplot [draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-10:10]
                 {3/2+x/2} \drawle; 
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10] {3-x}; 
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10] {-5+2*x}; 
        \addplot[very thick, domain=-10:10] {3/2+x/2}; 
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{Problem 4, Part A} 
  \end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is old but... how would you modify the code to consider the case of a vertical line (for example, $x_1 \geq 2$?

Answer (score 32):

I would not do this with *pgfplots* but with *TikZ* instead:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-1,-3) grid (5,4);
    \draw[very thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5.2,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
    \draw[very thick,->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$x_2$};

    \foreach \x in {-1,...,5} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
    \foreach \y in {-3,...,4} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};

    \fill[blue!50!cyan,opacity=0.3] (8/3,1/3) -- (1,2) -- (13/3,11/3) -- cycle;

    \draw (-1,4) -- node[below,sloped] {\tiny$x_1+x_2\geq3$} (5,-2);
    \draw (1,-3) -- (3,1) -- node[below left,sloped] {\tiny$2x_1-x_2\leq5$} (4.5,4);
    \draw (-1,1) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$-x_1+2x_2\leq3$} (5,4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: +1. How does one insert this picture in an article?

Comment: Just put it in the text, possibly in a figure environment: `text text \begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture} <draw commands> \end{tikzpicture}\caption{Inequalities}\end{figure} text text`

Comment: I was unable to get what I wanted because the figure without caption was inserted in a separated page.

Comment: You have to use a different `documentclass` (e.g. `scrartcl`), as `standalone` is just for single pictures.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I've managed with `\documentclass{article}`  `\usepackage{tikz}` ...  `\begin{center}` ...  `\end{center} `

Comment: I could not do what you doing. I have an article for documentclass but I cannot call this graph tex file into my original tex file.

Comment: @TomBombadil. Could you please add comments to your codes line by line for people like us who are new to graphing with Latex?  I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 16):

This seems like a very natural application for the `intersections` library. I personally *would* do this with `pgfplots`, using your framework as a starting point.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis on top,smooth,
            axis line style=very thick,
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            ymin=-1,ymax=6,xmin=-1,xmax=6,
            xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$,grid=major
            ]
            \addplot[name path global=firstline,very thick, domain=-10:10]{3-x};
            \addplot[name path global=secondline,very thick, domain=-10:10]{-5+2*x};
            \addplot[name path global=thirdline,very thick, domain=-10:10]{3/2+x/2};
            \fill[name intersections={of=firstline and secondline,by=point1},
            name intersections={of=firstline and thirdline,by=point2},
            name intersections={of=secondline and thirdline,by=point3},
            ][very thick,draw=orange,pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=green!60!white](point1)--(point2)--(point3)--(point1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Problem 4, Part A}
    \label{fig:p3:c1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that your `\label` should always go *after* your `\caption`.

Note that you need to use `name path global` as detailed in [Intersections in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots)

**Animation**

Just for fun, here's an animation

[image: animation]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\foreach \m in{0.5,1,...,5,4.5,4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis on top,smooth,
            axis line style=very thick,
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            ymin=-1,ymax=6,xmin=-1,xmax=6,
            xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$,grid=major
            ]
            \addplot[name path global=firstline,very thick,red, domain=-10:10]{\m-x};
            \addplot[name path global=secondline,very thick, domain=-10:10]{-5+2*x};
            \addplot[name path global=thirdline,very thick, domain=-10:10]{3/2+x/2};
            \fill[name intersections={of=firstline and secondline,by=point1},
            name intersections={of=firstline and thirdline,by=point2},
            name intersections={of=secondline and thirdline,by=point3},
            ][very thick,draw=orange,pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=green!60!white](point1)--(point2)--(point3)--(point1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

See [How to convert pstricks animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73545/how-to-convert-pstricks-animation-to-gif-file) for full details of the rest of the process (just a couple of steps).

Answer (score 12):

Just for fun.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl,graphicx}

\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\def\f(#1){#1 1 add}
\def\g#1{#1 neg 3 div 2 add}
\def\h#1{#1 neg 3 add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](-1,-2)(4,3)
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstInterFF{\f(x)}{\g{x}}{0}{A}%
    \pstInterFF{\g{x}}{\h{x}}{0}{B}%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.5]{
        \psline(!0 {\f(0)}/Y ED Y)
        \psplot{0}{N-A.x}{\f(x)/Y ED Y}
        \psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\g{x}}
        \psplot{N-B.x}{2.5}{\h{x}}
        \psline(2.5,0)
        \closepath}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\f(x)/Y ED Y}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\g{x}}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\h{x}}
    \psline(2.5,-2)(2.5,3)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.75)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,120]
\end{pspicture*}  

\end{document}
```

New features:

- `\psset{saveNodeCoors}`
- `\psline(!0 {\f(0)}/Y ED Y)`
- `\psplot{0}{N-A.x}{\f(x)/Y ED Y}`

### Latest update

Infix notation is used here for the sake of your convenience.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl,graphicx}


\def\f(#1){(#1+1)}
\def\g#1{(-(#1)/3+2)}
\def\h#1{(-(#1)+3)}

\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[saveNodeCoors,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](-1,-2)(4,3)
    \pstInterFF{{\f(x)} exec I2P}{\g{x} I2P}{0}{A}
    \pstInterFF{\g{x} I2P}{\h{x} I2P}{0}{B}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.5]
        {
        \psline(*0 {\f(x)})
        \psplot{0}{N-A.x}{{\f(x)} exec I2P}
        \psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\g{x} I2P}
        \psplot{N-B.x}{2.5}{\h{x} I2P}
        \psline(2.5,0)
        \closepath
        }
    \psplot{-1}{4}{{\f(x)} exec I2P}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\g{x} I2P}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\h{x} I2P}
    \psline(2.5,-2)(2.5,3)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.75)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,120]
\end{pspicture*}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Needs latest `pst-eucl.tex` from CTAN or http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-eucl/

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}

\def\f{x+1} \def\g{-x/3+2}  \def\h{-x+3}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[saveNodeCoors,algebraic,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](-1,-2)(4,3)
    \pstInterFF{\f}{\g}{0}{A} \pstInterFF{\g}{\h}{0}{B}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.5]{
        \psline(*0 {\f})
        \psplot{0}{N-A.x}{\f}
        \psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\g}
        \psplot{N-B.x}{2.5}{\h}
        \psline(2.5,0) }
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.75)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,120]
    \psset{linecolor=black!40}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\f}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\g}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\h}
    \psline(2.5,-2)(2.5,3)
\end{pspicture*}  

\end{document}
```

[image]