# Shade the area of an inequality

Tags: pgfplots, shading

I am looking for an easy answer of how to fill an area defined by an inequality like for example y >= 4 - x in latex.

I would also appreciate if you could tell where the options go as well, for example I might be intereseted in replacing the line by a dashed line or I might be interested that the area has transparency in case it croses with other areas.

As guidance, I would like to fill the area under the two straight lines of this picture:

[image]

KR

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `fillbetween` library that comes with `pgfplots`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183764

Comment: Please (as always) add a code for showed picture.

Comment: I think I've answered this before....

Comment: As you can see people have *ideas* what you are asking for and possible solutions. But we are not quite *sure* if we understood everything correctly. So please add some code what you have achieved so far and maybe a sketch of what *exactly* you want to achieve. Otherwise I think this question is either closed as "unclear what you are asking" or as "duplicate" with a questions that sounds similar to yours (like the one Schrödinger's cat proposed in the above comment).

Comment: it worked!! thanks, I will take that into account for the next one