# problem with intersection points in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Using `pgfplots` I have a region enclosed within three lines and the axes. I used the `intersections` library as indicated by [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76257/11162). The problem is that the intersections do not all seem to be correct. Since I am intersecting just lines with lines, there should be one intersection per pair of lines. Below is an MWE that produces the figure shown. I want the blue region to be the darkest red region that can be seen just peeping out from behind.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        enlargelimits={value=0.2,upper},
        scaled ticks=false, 
        minor x tick num=1,
        domain=0:8,
        ]
\addplot[name path global=line1, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]
{6}node[black,opacity=1,above]{line1}\closedcycle;

\draw[name path global=line2] ({axis cs:4,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:4,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1})node[pos=0.8,black,opacity=1,right]{line2};
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,domain=0:4] {12}\closedcycle;

\addplot[name path global=line3, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]
{(18-3*x)/2}node[sloped,pos=0.63,opacity=1,above]{line3}\closedcycle;


\fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by=point12},
      name intersections={of=line1 and line3,by=point13},
      name intersections={of=line2 and line3,by=point23},
      ][fill=blue](0,0)--(0,6)--(point13)node{13}--(point23)node{23}--(4,0)--(0,0);

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options in this case to fix the part that goes below 0:

1. Add `axis cs:` to the points in the `fill` command
2. The most recent version of [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is `1.11`. By changing the version, I am able to get the result you want with no other changes. This is probably because in `1.11`, the default coordinate system is `axis cs`.

I'll show #1 here, since that's marginally more complicated, and uses the same version you are using. Note that combining #1 and #2 causes no problems, and it should probably be preferred to use the most recent version in general.

In addition, the node `13` is misplaced because of the `\closedcycle` macro, there are multiple intersection points. In this case, you need the second intersection of `line1` and `line3`, which we can get by naming the first intersection point something else, and naming the second one by `point13`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        enlargelimits={value=0.2,upper},
        scaled ticks=false,
        minor x tick num=1,
        domain=0:8,
        ]
\addplot[name path global=line1, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]
{6}node[black,opacity=1,above]{line1}\closedcycle;

\draw[name path global=line2] ({axis cs:4,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:4,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1})node[pos=0.8,black,opacity=1,right]{line2};
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,domain=0:4] {12}\closedcycle;

\addplot[name path global=line3, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]
{(18-3*x)/2}node[sloped,pos=0.63,opacity=1,above]{line3}\closedcycle;


\fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by=point12},
      name intersections={of=line1 and line3,by={a,point13}},
      name intersections={of=line2 and line3,by=point23},
      ][fill=blue](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:0,6)--(point13)node{13}--(point23)node{23}--(axis cs:4,0)--(axis cs:0,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code produces the picture above, right? If so, then point13 is, like my code, not the intersection of the line1 and line3.

Comment: @Geoff Oh I didn't even notice that! The problem is due to the `\closedcycle` part, if you remove both of those the problem is solved but the fill goes away. Let me work a bit to fix it...

Comment: @Geoff Should be fixed now!

Comment: I get it now, the `\closedcycle` is obviously part of the path, hence "lines" have more than one intersection point!

Comment: Right. You can read more about this in section 13.3.2 of the PGF 3.0.0 manual :-)