# How to fill in inequality where all inequalities overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

After reading a question on "[How to draw the region of inequality?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75933/how-to-draw-the-region-of-inequality)", 
I have a code like this that refers to the inequalities

[image: inequality]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={
             \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque,
                          grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}

\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:0,1) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis line style=thin,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
ymin=-7, ymax=7, xmin=-7, xmax=7, xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\), grid=minor]
\addplot[name path global=line1, pattern=north west lines, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-7:7]{3*x-5};
\addplot[name path global=line2, pattern=north west lines, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-7:7]{6-2*x};
\addplot [draw=none, pattern=northeast lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-7:7]{3*x-5} \drawle;
\addplot [draw=none, pattern=northeast lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-7:7]{6-2*x} \drawge;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image: picture]

I want it to look like

[image: picture2], where the graph is filled only where all the inequalities hold true. NOTE the two graphs are entirely different problems. I only want the style, not the question.

However, the code for the latter image uses intersections:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis line style=thin,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    ymin=-6, ymax=7, xmin=-6, xmax=11, xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\), grid=minor]
    \addplot[name path global=line1, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-5:10]{5/3-x/3};
    \addplot[name path global=line2, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-5:10]{x/5-10/7};
    \addplot[name path global=line3, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-5:10]{6*x+10};
    \fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by=point1}, name intersections={of=line1 and line3,by=point2}, name intersections={of=line2 and line3,by=point3}][very thick, pattern=northeast lines, draw=blue!60, pattern color=blue!30!cyan](point1)--(point2)--(point3)--(point1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The first image has only one intersecting point, hence I cannot use this method. I also don't want other areas shaded- only the final areas where the lines intersect. Is there a way around it without to find the points in which the lines intersect the border of the grid, meaning I have to manually compute the points?

EDIT: added the inequalities for the graph.

Comment: I am not sure what the final result should look like. Could you edit the first plot manually and mark the stuff that should be shaded and which ones not?

Comment: Please see my edit, I put the inequalities.

Comment: your two inequalities can not determine your desired (second) image. Please, draw your equation by hand to see this.

Comment: @Zarko, I only want the first graph to have overlaps filled in (the other areas to be blank). I do not want the code for the second graph (I have the code). I just want the style of the code for the first graph.

Comment: @MatthewTang, then both answer should be satisfactory ... anyway, I will  add some more elements to my answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit:*
Since the graph are relatively simple, it is sensible to manually calculate coordinates of border lines at limits `ymin=-7` and `ymax=7` and their intersection:

- for line `3*x-5` are `(-2/3,-7)`, `(4,7)`
- for line `-2x+6` are `(1/2,7)`, `(6.5,-7)`
- intersection both lines is at `(11/5,8/5)`.

With known this point drawing desired image become simple. First draw path, which limit pattern area and than draw both lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[E/.style={font=\small,text=black, sloped, pos=0.84}]
    \begin{axis}[
axis line style=thin, axis lines=center,
xmin=-5, xmax=7,
ymin=-7, ymax=7,  
ytick={-6,-4,...,6},
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
grid=major,
                    ]
\path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40]
(4,7) -- (11/5,8/5) -- (6.5,-7) -- (6.5,7) -- cycle;
\draw[very thick, color=blue!50]
    (-2/3,-7) -- (4.0, 7) node[E,above] {$y\leq  3x-5$}
    (-0.5, 7) -- (6.5,-7) node[E,below] {$y\geq -2x+6$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can calculate intersection of both lines by use of `intersections` library, as Suggested *JPi* in his answer or consider the following slightly different pure `pgfplots` solution. The differences to the first example and *JPi* answer are designated by `% <--` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14, set layers}% <-- also works with 1.11
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[E/.style={font=\small,text=black, sloped, pos=0.75}]
    \begin{axis}[
axis line style=thick, % <--
     axis lines=center,% <--
    axis on top,
xmin=-5, xmax=7,
ymin=-7, ymax=7,
ytick={-6,-4,...,6},
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
grid=major,% <--
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=blue!50}% <--
                    ]
\addplot[name path=A,domain=-2:5] { 3*x-5} node[E,above] {$y\leq  3x-5$};
\addplot[name path=B,domain=-2:7] {-2*x+6} node[E,below] {$y\geq -2x+6$};
\path[name path=C] (0,7) -| (7,-7) -- (0,-7); 
    \path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={i1}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={i2}}];% <--
    \path[name intersections={of=B and C, by={i3}}];% <--
\pgfonlayer{pre main}% <--
\path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red]% <-- red is for better seeing that patterns are in background
    (i2) -- (i1) -- (i3) |- (i2);
\endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives almost the same result as it is obtained in the first example:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant the overlapping. Please see my edit, I put the inequalities.

Comment: Hi, one problem I encountered. I could not use the compat=1.14 mode for pgfplotsset. The compiler at sharelatex doesn't recognise it. I get the graph but no pattern fill.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sharelatex`, so don't know which version of `pgfplots` is there installed. About this please contact `sharelatex` people.  I test code with `pgfplots` 1.11 and MWE works. Try replace `1.14` with `newest`, maybe than will work.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end axis/.code={
             \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque,
                          grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}

\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:0,1) \closedcycle}
\newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0)\closedcycle}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis line style=thin,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
ymin=-7, ymax=7, xmin=-7, xmax=7, xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\), grid=minor]
\addplot[name path global=line1, pattern=north west lines, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-7:7]{3*x-5};
\addplot[name path global=line2, pattern=north west lines, color=blue!50, thick, domain=-7:7]{6-2*x};
\addplot [draw=none, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-7:7,samples=200]{min(3*x-5,6-2*x)} \drawle;
\addplot [draw=none, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-7:7, samples=1000]{max(6-2*x,3*x-5)}\drawge;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the overlapping. Please see my edit, I put the inequalities.