# pgfplots axis clipping large markers

Tags: pgfplots

In the example below the large markers at the axes are drawn over the axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, clip=true]

\addplot+[mark=*, mark size=3pt]
    coordinates {
    (0.0, 0)
    (0.2, 1)
    (0.4, 0.8)
    (0.6, 0)
    (0.8, 0)
    (1.0, 0)
    };

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead I would like the axes to clip the parts of the markers that leave the axis box area. Also, I would prefer the axis and the axis ticks drawn over
the marks. It should like this then:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `clip marker paths=true` instead of `clip=true` and add `axis on top=true` (thanks @Jake for the suggestion) in order to get the axes and the axes ticks drawn in the foreground.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, clip marker paths=true, axis on top=true]

\addplot+[mark=*, mark size=3pt]
    coordinates {
    (0.0, 0)
    (0.2, 1)
    (0.4, 0.8)
    (0.6, 0)
    (0.8, 0)
    (1.0, 0)
    };

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 And you might want to add `axis on top` to address the OP's final request.

Comment: @Jake Oh thanks. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @user24520: Yeah, that's possible using `set layers`. I thought we had a question about that that I could refer you to, but it doesn't seem like it. Could you open a new question that asks specifically about that (it's not really directly related to this question about clipping markers)? That would help other people who come across the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I looked for. But if I use axis on top in combination with the clipping also the grid lies before the marks. I found a solution for that under: [link] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/tikz-pgfplots-advanced-z-order-axis-grid

Comment: @user24520 That's good. I tried something with layers but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. That a solution to your problem could already be found on this site supports my suspicion that every possible piece of knowledge must already be here somewhere :)