# How to force markers under plot axes in pgfplots latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am looking for a way to force data markers near the graph axes to go under the axes.
An example where the markers go under the upper-left corner is the following:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: In case you use `pgfplots`, you can add the two options `clip marker paths, axis on top` to the `axis` environment. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135229/47927. If this is not what you are after, please edit your question to reopen it and provide more information, preferably including an MWE.