# pgfplots tick lines are behind const plot

Tags: pgfplots, plot, ticks

The tick lines in the plot are in a layer behind the actual plot. Have a look at this example below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,enlargelimits=false]
        \addplot
            [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
            coordinates
            {(0,0.1) (0.1,0.15) (0.15,0.02) (0.3,0.62)
            (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58) (0.6,0.65) (0.7,0.6)
            (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55) (1,0.52)}
        \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this plot:

[image: Image showing ticks behind the plot.]

It is clear that the plot has been drawn on top of the tick marks, the tick for 0.2 clearly shows this: it is mostly covered by the plot. I would be grateful if someone could guide me on how I can bring the tick marks ontop of the plot so those ticks on the bottom and right sides that are covered can be seen.

Comment: maybe this help [tikz-pgfplots-advanced-z-order-axis-grid](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/tikz-pgfplots-advanced-z-order-axis-grid)

Comment: The suggestions in the main answer to that question worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As selwyndd21 advised, I applied the suggestions of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/tikz-pgfplots-advanced-z-order-axis-grid) and the tiks are now clearly visible:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter \newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis} \makeatother

\pgfplotsset{axis line on top/.style={
  axis line style=transparent,
  ticklabel style=transparent,
  tick style=transparent,
  axis on top=false,
  after end axis/.append code={
    \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque,
      ticklabel style=opaque,
      tick style=opaque,
      grid=none}
    \pgfplotsdrawaxis}
  }
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,enlargelimits=false,axis line on top]
        \addplot
            [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
            coordinates
            {(0,0.1) (0.1,0.15) (0.15,0.02) (0.3,0.62)
            (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58) (0.6,0.65) (0.7,0.6)
            (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55) (1,0.52)}
        \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: const plot with ticks]